# How to configure a default Readme in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

When the create project button is clicked there is not an option to add a default Readme?

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 2):

The option to create a default `readme` file comes after you initialize the project.  Give your project a name and then click the green **Create project** button -- on the next screen, you should see this:

[image]

Click the **README** link to create a default `readme` file.